# Enabling SSL on Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, tomcat8

I've tried to follow both https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html and https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl (spent more time on the later), and neither seems to work for me.

When I try to follow the official tomcat guide, using my own self signed cert, I can not connect to either my webapp or to https://localhost:8443/ .

When I try to follow the mulesoft guide, I believe there is a typo in the last step of the guide

> "To import your new Certificate - keytool -import -alias [youralias] -keystore [path/to/your/keystore] -file [path/to/your_keystore] Do everything right? Then pat yourself on the back - you are now the
>   proud owner of a functional, certified keystore."

So I am unsure of what exactly to give the keystore.
I am using Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: Any errors in the Tomcat log file?

Comment: While trying to see if there was anything fishy in the log file, I played around in the server.xml and changed my port from 8443 to 4443 and it worked(using the tomcat official guide), It may be a Mac thing which I forgot to mention was my OS, I guess 8443 is just blocked on mac!

Comment: Or maybe port `8443` was already in use by another app, but the log file should have shown that.